# How to excute in Rest API if the return_url request lost after user has paid

Tags: rest, paypal

I am integrating Express Checkout payments in my web by using REST API, and setting the payment intent to sale for making an immediate payment.

Here follows my steps:
  1. create a direct payment by /v1/payments/payment, and set redirect_urls;
  2. redirect the buyer using the approval_url in the response of step1;
  3. when the buyer approves the payment, the full page will be redicrected to the url that I've been provided in redirect_urls, and then I will execute the payment to complete the payment.

My question here: 
what if the redirect_url lost in my step3? The buyer paid but I wouldn't be notified. I would not receive the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED webhook neither because I didn't execute the payment.

Comment: Finally find out. PayPal has webhooks for event notification. Webhooks help when return_url request lost. For me, I use 'PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED' event.

Comment: link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/